# Max limit of MultipartFile in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload

Is there a maximum file size that spring boot can handle in a `MultipartFile` upload process. I know that I can set the `maxFileSize` in the property like `multipart.maxFileSize=1Mb`.

So, like that can I allow a huge file to upload, like 50MB. The application runs on the Tomcat server integrated with Spring Boot. Do I need to configure the tomcat server also? Or is the file size *unlimited*?

Comment: as far as I know, it's better to set maxFileSize and maxRequestSize... good question anyway!

Comment: i want to what is the maxfile size it can handle.

Comment: Unlimited is never a good thing for stuff like this. Better to set it to a large number - bigger than you would ever expect. Someone uploads a file larger than that, and it may very well be an attack, and you'll be grateful for that `IllegalStateException` that saved your site.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

***For unlimited upload file size***

It seems setting `-1` will make it for infinite file size.

**Before Spring Boot 2.0:**

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

**After Spring Boot 2.0:**

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Comment: For more specific: 

    `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB`
    `spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB`

Comment: I tested this solution and it worked for me. 400GB file uploaded! I didn't have to configure nothing else because i'm using jetty.
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1 spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1 as sugested by @jimmbraddock

Comment: As in test, we never know what size of the file a user will input, this answer is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 141):

For those using Spring Boot 2.0 (as of M1 release), the property names have changed to:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Note the prefix is `spring.servlet` instead of `spring.http`.

Comment: Tried looking for difference between these two but no luck. Can you please share some reference?

Comment: If your request has multiple files then max-request-size will be limit of size combining all files.

Comment: make sure you dont leave space such as 10 MB. 
correct: it should be 10MB

Comment: Defaults can be found in [the official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web) (search for "multipart")

Answer (score 34):

In my `application.yml` file

```
spring:
 servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 15MB
      max-request-size: 15MB
```

And If you have `application.properties` file

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 15MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 15MB
```

Even You can set file size to infinite

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size =-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size =-1
```

Comment: Note: For a .yml file, your file size still needs to be capitalized. 15MB instead of 15Mb.

Answer (score 15):

Spring Boot have embbeed Tomcat with it so we don't need to configure it. MULTIPART properties in application-properties will take care of it.

For an external server, the default limit is `50MB`. We can see it by opening `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

**MULTIPART properties have been changed according to versions.**

*Spring Boot 1.3.x and earlier*

```
multipart.max-file-size
multipart.max-request-size
```

*After Spring Boot 1.3.x:*

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

*After Spring Boot 2.0:*

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `multipart.max-file-size=128MB` and `multipart.max-request-size=128MB` works for me without additional configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This gonna work

```html
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 4GB
      max-request-size: 4GB
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for the answer, What is maximum size we can upload with multiPartFile in springboot application but i have used 450mb successfully and it took approx 10min to do that. Below is the only configuration i did in application.properties file to make it work :

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500MB
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3+ and tomcat 10+ `server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=4000MB` is the properties you are looking for. All the others are not working for setting the max file size