# Unable to upload files larger than 1 MB

Tags: apache, spring-boot, file-upload, multipart

I am trying to upload files larger than 1Mb with spring boot

```
hereorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:618) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max Limit of MultipartFile in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177873/max-limit-of-multipartfile-in-spring-boot)

Comment: may be but i am not able to upload still, i have done evrey thing what is there in that ticket.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring 2.0 or higher add the below code which is working for me

> application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

> application.yml

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 128MB
      max-request-size: 128MB
```

If you just want to control the `multipart properties` then `multipart.max-file-size` and `multipart.max-request-size` properties should work.

Answer (score 4):

File uploading problem solved by this configuration in application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: testone
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      maxFileSize: 500MB
      maxRequestSize: 500MB
      file-size-threshold: 500MB
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using application.yml

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
```

or

If you are using application.properties

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

Hope it will works

Comment: i am using like this:

spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      maxFileSize: -1l
      maxRequestSize: -1l

Comment: @ShivakumarN  -1 will allow you upload any file size.

Comment: In swagger :

{
  "timestamp": "2018-03-19T05:54:07.990+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (56976406) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)",
  "path": "/yt/video/upload"
}

Comment: change configuration and restart server

Comment: Dude set limit according your file size, it seems your file is larger than 50 MB

Comment: yes i need upload video file bro... so it can be near to 500 MB, but if file is 20 MB it will works fine, problem is in large file upload only

Comment: that's I'm saying just replace `50MB` to `500MB`.

Comment: set the `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1  `

Comment: spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      maxFileSize: -1
      maxRequestSize: -1

but still

Comment: Sry dude, Please refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration

Comment: Many times told you please set only `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size`