# springboot controller how to receive a limited string?

Tags: spring-boot

My springboot version is 2.0.2 ,My controller could receive the request param .While The controller wants to receive a 16-megabyte string.How to specify the spring boot config params?

Comment: There is a limitation on max length of request parameter (as query param) or as request body. I don't think it is a good idea to send 16MBs of data as request param. Rather use multi-part request.

Comment: I am curious what might be the use-case for a 16 MB requestParam?

Comment: @Manmay, how to specify the limitation ,could you provide some param config ?  It may be 1MB.

Comment: spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177873/max-limit-of-multipartfile-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Manmay It could not help me ,  some controller url may upload a larger file(which is 10MB), while my expected controller url may not exceed 1M, so I can set   spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB, but I do not want my expected url param exceed 1MB.  How to set?

Comment: Then you can set the size to 1MB instead of 10 MB in the config