# Unable to set maximum value for "spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size" in spring boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload

What is the maximum value which can be set for "spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size" for multipart uploads in spring boot 2?

Can we set it to unlimited?, I have read on the other blogs that setting it to -1 will allow unlimited but it didn't work for me.

I tried putting this in `application.properties` but was of no help

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

UPDATE:

1) When I post a file using Postman which is less than 10MB my file gets uploaded and in another scenario I get

```
{
    "timestamp": 1551270385443,
    "message": "java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760",
    "path": "v1/order/upload/"
}
```

which is equivalent to the response I get if I don't configure the `max-file-size` and `max-request-size property` in `application.properties`

The tutorial which I am using: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

2)

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1024MB
```

the above configuration allows me to upload file greater than 10MB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max Limit of MultipartFile in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177873/max-limit-of-multipartfile-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

and an uploading tutorial here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

I am pretty sure your properties are correct.

You haven't provided any code or other properties so below is my suspision only:

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1` is one thing, but together with it, you should also set `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` accordingly because it might be the case that the whole request is rejected.

Comment: I tried configuring the max-request-size also but still getting the exception, I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Then it sounds mysterious :) are you sure your `application.properties` are in the correct place and being picked up?

Comment: lol, yes it is in the correct place and the reason behind that is I have been able to change those configurations to different sizes and upload them successfully without any issues, it's just the -1 config which I am having issues with.

Comment: and what happens if you explicitly set the value from -1 to lets say 100MB and then send, i.e 15MB request? Can you try it?

Comment: I just tested it on my test-project. I set up properties like you and successfully uploaded 20MB+ file... My spring-boot version is 2.1.1 - what is yours?

Comment: yes, I tried uploading a 13.7MB file with 100MB as setting and it works fine, I am able to upload the file successfully.

Comment: mine is 2.0.0, what did you set for "spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size" ? , and I was able to set the "spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1" and "spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10240MB" and I was able to upload a 80 MB file but i am still not able to upload file larger than default size with max-request-size set to -1.

Comment: I just copied properties from your question so those were `-1`s.

Comment: Further update: also worked for `2.0.0.RELEASE`. Please share your pom.xml maybe?