# How to upload a large file to ftps server in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftps

I want to upload a file to the ftps server. The below code works for small files like 10KB. but I need to upload 5-10 MB files. and the error comes with the below error line. Can someone help me with this? Below code which I tried. Is there a better way to do this?

**Error Line**

```
boolean result = con.storeFile(FILE_NAME, multipartFile.getInputStream());
```

**Code**

```
public void createDeviceVersion(MultipartFile multipartFile) {

 String FTP_ADDRESS = backendConfigRepo.findByConfigKey(KeyConstant.FTP_ADDRESS).getConfigValue();
 int FTP_PORT = Integer.parseInt(backendConfigRepo.findByConfigKey(KeyConstant.FTP_PORT).getConfigValue());
 String USER = backendConfigRepo.findByConfigKey(KeyConstant.FTP_USER).getConfigValue();
 String PASSWORD = backendConfigRepo.findByConfigKey(KeyConstant.FTP_PASSWORD).getConfigValue();
 String FILE_NAME = backendConfigRepo.findByConfigKey(KeyConstant.MCASH_VERSION_FILE_NAME).getConfigValue();
 FTPSClient con = null;

 try {
  con = new FTPSClient(true);
  con.connect(FTP_ADDRESS, FTP_PORT);

  if (con.login(USER, PASSWORD)) {
   con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
   con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
   boolean result = con.storeFile(FILE_NAME, multipartFile.getInputStream());
   System.out.println(result);
   con.logout();
   con.disconnect();

  }

 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

Error Message

> org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught
>   while copying.    at
>   org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:136)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:639)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:2160)
>       .... Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: why don't you try using some ssh libraries like JSch, SSHJ? Any limitations?

Comment: I don't know much about ftps servers. I just wanna upload a file to ftps server. what you meant by limitations?  this error comes with, storeFile line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with changing max size in `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`?
I think this might help you [Max limit of multi part file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177873/max-limit-of-multipartfile-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Yes, I already did.

# Multipart Content Configs
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=5KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=515MB
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false

thanks.