# Getting Maximum upload size exceeded exception while uploading a large file through postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, tomcat, multipartform-data

Spring boot application.
I have a rest endpoint for uploading a multipart file.

```
 Controller.java
 @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("folder") String folder) {
        tests.uploadFile(file, folder);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

Getting the following exception while uploading 5MB file in POSTMAN.
[image]

Spring boot version is 2.0.6.
I have tried the following methods.

1)spring:
tomcat:
max-http-form-post-size: 500MB
max-swallow-size: 500MB

2)spring:
servlet:
multipart:
max-file-size: 500MB
max-request-size: 500MB
enabled: true

3)spring:
servlet:
multipart:
max-file-size: -1
max-request-size: -1
enabled: true

Still i am getting this same exception. When i try to upload a small file of size less than 1 mb i am able to process it, but when i try to upload a file of size 5mb or greater i am not able to debug or process it.

Can someone help me on this .
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set max file limit according to your spring version as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810158/10961238

Comment: Added still getting this exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in my application , only has these simple configurations in application.yml

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 500MB
      max-request-size: 500MB
```

Comment: I added these configurations and checked in my application. Still i m getting the same exception. Why is that ? 

 threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.]

Comment: @MithunManohar Is there any other configurations in your application.yml/application.properties or any other dependencies in your project ? My testing application is just a simple project that only contains "spring-boot-starter-web" module.spring boot version 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: The issue is resolved the problem was with my application.yml file 
I was adding these configurations just below the three dashes that is why it was not working for me.
Actually it has to be above those three dashes.